# Exact Taylor expansion of order 1

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Can we prove that for any differentiable function $f: R^n \rightarrow R$,
$f(y)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(z)$, for some $z$ on the line segment $[x, y]$.

Note that it is not approximation, it is exact equality. I am skeptical because this is similar to the mean value theorem which should only apply when f is on a closed interval.

---

We have for a closed interval [a,b] by MVT

$$f(a) = f(b) + f'(ta + (1 - t)b)(a-b)$$

...

Comment: This is a generalization of the mean value theorem. Apply it to $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(t):= f(tx+(1-t)y)$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are fixed

Comment: I do not understand what you want to show with your example.

Comment: It is not an example. Use the mean value theorem on $f$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really do not see where you want to go.